# buttons disappear after redrawing and show up again when mouse moved in

Tags: button, wxpython

dear Sirs:

I am using wxPython to draw some window background and buttons. 
I redrew the background panel with memoryDC and then save the background image to staticbitmap. 
I also declared some buttons on top of the background window. 
When I redrew the background, the buttons just disappear.
Then when I moved the cursor across those buttons, they appear again.
I tried to Raise() the buttons.
But that did not work.

The solution now is to destroy the buttons and then re-instantiate them again after redrawing the background of the windows. 
But is there any more efficient way to do this without having to reconstruct the button objects.

Thanks

Farn

Comment: We probably cannot help if you do not show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike Driscoll posted a nice [example for background bitmap in wxPython in his blog](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-putting-a-background-image-on-a-panel/). Note the code update at the end of his post required for Versions >= 2.9.

Comment: You can accept the answer, if you found a hint in the link above how to solve your problem. Otherwise, also a feedback "answer did not help because of [reasons]" is interesting for posterity.

Comment: Thank you!  I will now do my duty in actively participating the discussion.